# `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` while using `PyList_New' in C

Tags: python, c, macos

I was trying to use C extends Python. I need to get some data from C and return them to Python.
So I write code like this:

`C code`

```
PyObject *hello4(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *dict = PyDict_New();

    PyObject *list = PyList_New(4640);
    int cnt=0;
    for (int i=0; i!=4640; ++i){
        PyObject *sublist = PyList_New(64);
        for (int j=0; j!=64; ++j){
            PyList_SetItem(sublist, j, Py_BuildValue("i", i*100+j));
        }
        printf("%d\n", cnt++);
        PyList_SetItem(list, i, sublist);
        printf("len(list) : %d\n", (int)PyList_Size(list));
    }
    PyDict_SetItem(dict, Py_BuildValue("s", "Y"), list);

    return dict;
}
```

`Python code`

```
import ctypes
so = ctypes.CDLL("./libhello.so")
hello4func = so.hello4
hello4func.restype = ctypes.py_object
ret = hello4func()
print ret
```

I need to create many block (maybe more than 4640).
But when I running the Python code, it crashed when creating the 124 PyList(116 in my another code)
Does anybody know how to fix it?

> Process:         Python [983] Path:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   Identifier:      Python Version:         2.7.5 (2.7.5) Code Type:
>   X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:  bash [541] Responsible:     Terminal
>   [339] User ID:         501
>
> PlugIn Path:       /Users/USER/*/libhello.so PlugIn Identifier:
>   libhello.so PlugIn Version:    ??? (0)
>
> Date/Time:       2015-01-02 20:40:41.568 +0800 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.9.5 (13F34) Report Version:  11 Anonymous UUID: 
>   65B6A8E2-79EC-56D0-F276-A4E7578D3150
>
> Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000048
>
> VM Regions Near 0x48:
>   --> 
>       __TEXT                 00000001043be000-00000001043bf000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   org.python.python                 0x0000000104455fe0 PyErr_Occurred + 14
>   1   org.python.python                 0x0000000104478179
>   _PyObject_GC_Malloc + 114 2   org.python.python               0x0000000104478203 _PyObject_GC_New + 18 3   org.python.python
>     0x00000001043f2097 PyList_New + 119 4   libhello.so
>     0x00000001046dee6a hello4 + 58 5   libffi.dylib
>     0x00007fff8bd19f9c ffi_call_unix64 + 76 6   libffi.dylib
>     0x00007fff8bd1a78e ffi_call + 790 7   _ctypes.so
>     0x00000001046c490e _ctypes_callproc + 794 8   _ctypes.so
>     0x00000001046bef80 0x1046bc000 + 12160 9   org.python.python
>     0x00000001043d1f72 PyObject_Call + 101 10  org.python.python
>     0x000000010444bdf5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15416 11  org.python.python
>     0x0000000104448093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641 12  org.python.python
>     0x0000000104447a24 PyEval_EvalCode + 54 13  org.python.python
>     0x0000000104466c2c 0x1043c8000 + 650284 14  org.python.python
>     0x0000000104466cd3 PyRun_FileExFlags + 137 15  org.python.python
>     0x0000000104466821 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 718 16 
>   org.python.python                 0x0000000104477363 Py_Main + 2995 17 
>   libdyld.dylib                     0x00007fff8e5635fd start + 1

Comment: Looks like a problem that is not really related to your code shown above - there is nothing you can do wrong using PyList_New. So the question is - is that all code you are running?

Comment: My codes are here: [code](https://github.com/JaySon-Huang/misc/tree/master/PythonCallC) @deets

Comment: When I compile & execute as documented, I get some output including a few lists and no error. I'm on OSX, too - so maybe this is an issue with your Python-interpreter? Can you try using a different one? I use e.g. the downloaded Python2.7 from python.org, and this is what libhello.so is linked against then.

Comment: I am using the default version of python which is pre-install in Mac OS, the python 2.7.5. I think the option `-framework Python` may be link to python 2.7.5 automatically..

Comment: I try to compile & execute it under Ubuntu, and it throw `Segmentation fault` the same as it run under Mac OS...

Comment: Hm, strange. Sorry, if that's happening there, too, I can't be of help. My only suggestion would be to build a debug-Python on Ubuntu, and try & see what happens more precisely.

Comment: I successfully run by using `gcc example3.c -fPIC -shared -o libhello.so -I/usr/include/python2.7 -std=c99` & `python3.3 pyex3.py` under Ubuntu. It seems that it is a bug in python2.7.5 ...T^T

Comment: But I can't compile the source code under Mac OS,`gcc example3.c -fPIC -shared -o libhello.so -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/`this will report that`_PyDict_New` and other Python C API is Undefined symbols.How can I fix the path of dynamic library for using python3?

Comment: I doubt it's a bug. This is too obivous an issues. Probably the problem is more along the lines of you linking against one interpreter, but using a different one to run the extension, or some such. For giving linker paths, use the -L and -l options.